# Only change variable if it's current value is non nil Swift

Tags: swift, option-type

What is the best way to keep a variable or object property the same, but if it does not exist, set a default value.

I currently do:

```
optionalVar = optionalVar ?? defaultValue
```

However, sometimes, I get an error like:

```
Thread 1: Simultaneous accesses to 0x103a854b8, but modification requires exclusive access
```

and sometimes I don't, so i don't think that this is the best approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entering a statement like you have:

```
x = x ?? y
```

will always result into an assignment, you will either re-assign the same value or assign a new value y. As you have experienced when attempting to perform this on multiple threads, once in a while more than one thread will access the variable at the same time.

You will likely want to use the longer form of your logic:

```
if optionalVar == nil {
  optionalVal = default
}
```

Not as pretty, but if the value is already defined, it will not be re-assigned.  Alternatively you could use a Mutex/NSLock to ensure only one thread at a time may set a value to this variable.

Comment: Ok, I already knew that, but it is the uglier approach I was hoping to avoid.

Comment: You could always create a getter for optionalVar which returns a default value if nil, or define a default value as soon as the variable is instantiated, or even a custom setter that skips the assignment if the value is the same.  then keep your code the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you think using an if statement is too "ugly", you can always wrap it with a custom operator:

```
infix operator =?

func =?<T>(left: inout T?, right: T?) {
    if left == nil {
        left = right
    }
}

var str: String? = nil
str =? "Hello"
str =? "Bye" // "str" is still "Hello"
```

Comment: While really cool I think this would make it hard to maintain down the road